# How can I check my public IP with limited access to internet?

Tags: windows, networking, internet

Guys I only have a social media bundle from my ISP and I would like to check my public IP address.
I can only access whatsapp, instagram, facebook, tiktok, telegram etc.

My router is Huawei B310, my phone is Samsung android 10 and I have windows 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With such limited plans, it is *very* likely that your public IP address will be dynamic (e.g. changing every day) and/or even shared with other customers (aka CGNAT).

1. Log in to your router's settings panel – it will have a status page showing your current IP address. This might be at `http://192.168.8.1` or similar. (Look for a sticker on the back of the router.)
2. Check whether any service can tell you the address that it saw you connecting from. For example, on Facebook (PC) you can open *Settings → Security and Login* to get a list of locations that you're logged in from. If you mouse-over a specific location under "Where You're Logged In", you'll see a tooltip with the corresponding IP address.